# Set the working folder for a remote process using WMI

Tags: wmi, process, remote-process, working-directory

I'm using [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Remote_Process_using_WMI_.aspx?fid=1531475&select=2815994#xx2815994xx) to start a process on a remote machine using WMI. How can I control the working directory that process will start in?

(No need to redirect me to psexec, I'm getting an error from it, currently trying the WMI approach).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389388(VS.85).aspx) and extrapolated.

A slight modification to the code in the article:

inParams["CurrentDirectory"] = @"c:\WorkingDirectory";